# How do I classify an array so it returns the greatest integer result of combining those natural numbers

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, function

Hi i will like to know how can classify an array so it returns the greatest integer result of combining those natural numbers

My code :

```
<label for="">Numbers</label><br><br>
<input type="text" id="Number"><br><br>
<button  type="button" name="button" onclick="test()">Submit</button>

function test() {

var numbers = document.getElementById("Number").value;

  sorted = numbers.split(" ").sort(function(a, b){

      return b-a;

});
```

but that dosnt classify them in natural numbers, instead from greatest to least
Thanks

Comment: please add an example of input and wanted output.

Comment: Input: 50 9 17 0 Output: 950170

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) without callback for sorting strings.

```js
function test() {
    var numbers = document.getElementById("Number").value,
        result = numbers.split(" ").sort().reverse().join('');

    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<label for="">Numbers</label><br><br>
<input type="text" id="Number"><br><br>
<button type="button" name="button" onclick="test()">Submit</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```